# ReactJS: How do you display an array of SVGs horizontally while maintaining their size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to horizontally display an SVG for each element in a mapped array. I've tried multiple things but the only thing that has worked so far has been setting the `div` that the mapped SVGs are contained in to `display: "flex"`. However, that introduced a new problem where whenever an element is added to or taken away from the state, the SVGs shrink/expand respectively. I was wondering if anyone could help me troubleshoot how to get these SVGs to be displayed horizontally while maintaining the same size no matter how many there are. My code is available below.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [states, setStates] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {states.map((state, stateIndex) => (
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 35">
          <rect fill={"black"} width={"25"} height={"25"} />
        </svg>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also made a Code Sandbox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/nervous-forest-jgwwhr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated to codesand box code if you can see yodate

Please try this solution.

```
  <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  {states.map((state, stateIndex) => (
    <div style={{ flex: "0 0 auto",width:"25%" }}>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 35" >
        <rect fill={"black"} width={"25"} height={"25"} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Update your App.js return data with this one.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I'll try to look over it and see if I can find an explanation for why it did.

Comment: It is row and col, which we used in bootstrap.
I just converted the data row and col class to CSS and it's worked.